# How to find space taken by a folder on disk?

Tags: bash, shell, disk-usage

I have a folder `/opt/XYZ`. To calculate space taken by it I use a mixture of `ls -lR` and `awk` to add space taken. It is a cumbersome way of finding disk space.

I was hoping for a simpler way of finding total space taken by a folder, inclusive of subfolders and files, else i will have to convert the commandline into a shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `du`.

My most common usage is `# du . -h` for current directory and subdirectories.

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/du1.html

The 'Root Users' website has some decent examples: https://www.rootusers.com/13-du-disk-usage-command-examples-in-linux/

Comment: the `-s` options is particularly useful, I find.

Comment: `du -h /opt/XYZ` worked. I tried with `-s` however the i could not make sense of the number that is displayed. Im accepting the answer given above as it worked for me.